# How are python library functions are called when we implement multithreading/multiprocessing (parallelization)

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to understand how parallelization works in python when we call python library functions in a parallelized user function.

For example, consider this simple code where I'm just sorting the multiple arrays through multithreading.

```
import threading
import numpy as np

def funk(x):
    print(np.sort(x)) 

a = np.array([3,4,2,1])
b = np.array([5,8,6,7])
c = np.array([9,2,1,4])
d = np.array([6,1,5,2])

threads= []
array_list = [a,b,c,d]
for each in array_list:
  t1 = threading.Thread(target = funk, args = [each])    
  t1.start()
  threads.append(t1)
  
for x in threads:
    x.join()
```

The library function `np.sort()` is in the user define function `funk` which is threaded and called 4 times concurrently.

My question is,

1. Does the function `np.sort` is also called concurrently by those 4 threads or do the other threads have to wait until the one thread calls and executes `np.sort()`?
2. Does this same behavior observed while calling other python library functions (not necessarily numpy).

NOTE: My question is not specific to multithreading or multiprocessing. I want to infer this query on every parallelization process.

Comment: Try this: *import time* then add *time.sleep(1)* after the print statement in *funk()* and run your program. You will see that the *np.sort()* functions are called for every array before the threads have completed.

Comment: yes, I noticed that. Also, the `time.sleep` is a library function which has been called concurrently. So does this suppose to mean that the library functions are called concurrently?

Comment: Yes - that is what happens

Comment: Consider reading [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) to understand better how it works.